# How to Display Linked List in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int ID;
    char Name;
    char Pos;
    struct node*next;
};

struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *createList(struct node*);
struct node *displayList(struct node *);

int main()
{
    start=createList(start);
    start = displayList(start);
    return 0;
}

struct node *createList(struct node *start)

{
    struct node *new_node, *ptr;
    int EmpID;
    char EmpName;
    char EmpPos;
    int choice;
    printf("\n Enter the Employee's ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &EmpID);
    printf("\n Enter the Employee's Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &EmpName);
    printf("\n Enter the Employee's Position: ");
    scanf("%s", &EmpPos);
    printf("\n Do you want to add more Employees [Press Any Number Key if 'yes', Press 1 for 'No']: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice != 1)
    {
        new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node ->ID=EmpID;
        new_node ->Name =EmpName;
        new_node ->Pos =EmpPos;
        if (start==NULL)
        {
            new_node -> next= NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr=start;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                 ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node -> next =NULL;

        }
        printf("\n Enter the Employee's ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &EmpID);
        printf("\n Enter the Employee's Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &EmpName);
        printf("\n Enter the Employee's Position: ");
        scanf("%s", &EmpPos);
        printf("\n Do you want to add more Employees [Press Any Number Key if 'yes', Press 1 for 'No']: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    return start;
};

struct node *displayList(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = start;
    while(ptr !=NULL)
    {
        printf("\t\n Employee's ID: ","%d, ", ptr->ID);
         ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("\t\n Employee's Name: ","%s, ", ptr->Name);
         ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("\t\n Employee's Position: ","%s, ", ptr->Pos);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
};
```

My code does not display the links even though there are no errors. How to display it? My Expected output should be like this :

Enter the Employee's ID: 10

Enter the Employee's Name: Lisa

Enter the Employee's Position: CEO

Do you want to add more Employees [Press Any Number Key if 'yes', Press 1 for 'No']: 5

Enter the Employee's ID: 9

Enter the Employee's Name: Rowena

Enter the Employee's Position: COO

Do you want to add more Employees [Press Any Number Key if 'yes', Press 1 for 'No']: 1

Employee's ID: 10, 9

Employee's Name: Lisa, Rowena

Employee's Position: CEO, COO

---

My code did not display anything when I press 1.

[image]

Comment: You're advancing to the next node in the list after printing value in the node, instead of just once after printing all 3.

Comment: Just as a side note: You are duplicating your code; with a do-while loop you would avoid that: `do { /* get input */; /*create node*/; } while(choice != 1);`

Comment: In you struct, change the datatypes for your Name and position to a `char *`, because you want to store their names with strings, and use `strdup`  when you create the new node to store their names.

Comment: If using `scanf` you should check its return value to catch invalid input. Generally: Reading entire lines with e.g. `fgets` and extracting specific input with `sscanf` (again check the return value) is a safer variant for input reading.

Comment: Your `displayList` function is declared to return a pointer to `struct node`, but returns nothing. You should either make this a `void` function, or let this function return something useful.

Answer (score 3):

Immediate problem:

```
struct node
{
    int ID;
    char Name;        // Can only store *single* characters
    char Pos;         // not strings
    struct node*next;
};
```

As defined, `Name` and `Pos` can only store *single* characters, not strings - you'll either have to define these as *arrays* of `char`:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20 // or however long a name can be
#define MAX_POS_LEN  20 // or however long a pos can be

struct node {
  int ID;
  char Name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1]; // +1 for string terminator
  char Pos[MAX_POS_LEN + 1];  
  struct node *next;
};
```

Or, you'll have to define them as *pointers* to `char`:

```
struct node {
  int ID;
  char *Name;
  char *Pos;
  struct node *next;
};
```

and allocate memory for them separately when you create the node:

```
// read EmpID, EmpName, EmpPos
...
struct node *n = malloc( sizeof *n );
if ( n )
{
  n->Name = calloc( strlen( EmpName) + 1, sizeof *n->Name );
  if ( n->Name )
     strcpy( n->Name, EmpName );
  else
     // handle allocation failure

  n->Pos  = calloc( strlen( EmpPos ) + 1, sizeof *n->Pos );
  if ( n->Pos )
     strcpy( n->Pos, EmpPos );
  else
     // handle allocation failure
}
```

Same problem with `EmpName` and `EmpPos` in your input function:

```
char EmpName;  // EmpName can only store a *single* character
char EmpPos;   // same with EmpPos
...
scanf( "%s", &EmpName );
...
scanf( "%s", &EmpPos );
```

This isn't going to work as you expect - if you type an input like `"Smith"` for `EmpName`, the `'S'` will be saved to `EmpName` and the remaining characters will be written to memory *outside* of `EmpName`, overwriting other data.

For input, `EmpName` and `EmpPos` *definitely* need to be declared as *arrays* of `char`:

```
char EmpName[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
char EmpPos[MAX_POS_LENGTH+1];
```

and if they need to be able to store spaces (like `"John Smith"`), then you can't use `scanf` with `%s` - you'll either have to use the `%[` specifier like

```
scanf( "%[^\n]", EmpName ); // read everything up to the newline
//              ^
//              +---------- note no & operator here
```

or, better yet, ditch `scanf` altogether and use `fgets` instead:

```
if ( fgets( EmpName, sizeof EmpName, stdin ) )
  // process EmpName
else
  // input error
```

In your `displayList` function, you're advancing the node pointer after printing each element:

```
while(ptr !=NULL)
{
    printf("\t\n Employee's ID: ","%d, ", ptr->ID);
     ptr = ptr->next;
    printf("\t\n Employee's Name: ","%s, ", ptr->Name);
     ptr = ptr->next;
    printf("\t\n Employee's Position: ","%s, ", ptr->Pos);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

IOW, you're printing the `ID` of the first node, then the `Name` of the second node, then the `Pos` of the third node.  Instead, it should be:

```
while(ptr !=NULL)
{
    printf("\t\n Employee's ID: ","%d, ", ptr->ID);
    printf("\t\n Employee's Name: ","%s, ", ptr->Name);
    printf("\t\n Employee's Position: ","%s, ", ptr->Pos);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

I also think you have your `\t` and `\n` backwards - you're going to print a tab, followed by a newline, so each item will print at the beginning of a line.  If that's what you want, then you can ditch the `\t` completely, it doesn't really add anything.  If you want each item to be inset by one tab stop, then you'll need to reverse them - `\n\t`.

---

It would be a good idea to write your I/O functions to operate on single nodes, rather than the entire list:

```
void displayNode( struct node *n )
{
  printf( "\tEmployee ID:       %d\n", n->ID );
  printf( "\tEmployee Name:     %s\n", n->Name );
  printf( "\tEmployee Position: %s\n", n->Pos );
}
```

and call that from a function that iterates through the list:

```
void displayList( struct node *head )
{
  for ( struct node *cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next )
    displayNode( cur );
}
```

Similarly, split out input, node creation, and node insertion into separate functions:

```
struct node *head = NULL;

int EmpId;
char EmpName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
char EmpPos[MAX_POS_LEN + 1];

while ( !done )
{
  if ( getNodeData( &EmpId, EmpName, sizeof EmpName, EmpPos, sizeof EmpPos ) )
  {
    struct node *n = createNode( EmpId, EmpName, EmpPos );
    if ( n )
    {
      insertList( &head, n );
    }
    else
    {
      // handle allocation error
      done = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // handle input error
    done = true;
  }

  if ( !done )
  {
    fputs( "Add another node? [Y/N]: ", stdout );
    int c = getchar();
    done = toupper( c ) == 'Y';
  }
}
```

where `getNodeData` looks something like

```
bool getNodeData( int *id, char *name, size_t nameSize, char *pos, size_t posSize )
{
  fputs( "Enter employee ID: ", stdout );
  if ( scanf( "%d", id ) != 1 )
  {
    fputs( "Error reading emp ID\n", stderr );
    return false;
  }

  fputs( "Enter employee name: ", stdout );
  if ( !fgets( name, nameSize, stdin ) )
  {
    fputs( "Error reading Emp Name\n", stderr );
    return false;
  }

  fputs( "Enter employee position: ", stdout );
  if ( !fgets( pos, posSize, stdin ) )
  {
    fputs( "Error reading Emp Position\n", stderr );
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and `createNode` looks something like

```
struct node *createNode( int id, const char *name, const char *pos )
{
  struct node *n = calloc( 1, sizeof *n );
  if ( n )
  {
    n->Name = calloc( strlen( name ) + 1, sizeof *n->Name );
    if ( !n->Name )
    {
      fputs( "Allocation failure on n->Name!\n", stderr );
      free( n );
      n = NULL;
    }
    else
      strcpy( n->Name, name );

    n->Pos = calloc( strlen( n->Pos ) + 1, sizeof *n->Pos );
    if ( !n->Pos )
    {
      fputs( "Allocation failure on n->Pos!\n", stderr );
      free( n->Name );
      free( n );
      n = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      strcpy( n->Pos, pos );
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

and `insertList` looks something like

```
void insertList( struct node **head, struct node *n )
{
  if ( !*head )
    *head = n;
  else
  {
    struct node *cur = *head;
    while ( cur->next != NULL )
      cur = cur->next;
    cur->next = n;
  }
}
```

This allows you to test each piece in isolation, and makes it easier to reason through and fix your code.